# How to use hudson tracker with a Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, hudson

I am very new to ruby on rails.. working on my first project...

am using Ankh SVN for source control... I want to use Hudson tracker also...

I tried it on my own but not able to succeed... i have not used any build files at all... but when i hit build now it fails and when i see the console output it says

```
U         test\unit\product_test.rb
At revision 3
[trunk] $ rake.bat
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2 (you have 1.3.1). Please `gem update --system` and try again.
(in E:/Server Data/Hudson Data/jobs/Depot-Rails Testing/workspace/trunk)
Finished: FAILURE
```

have no idea what to do now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and run:

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: @zx12r sure, no problem, you're starting up! Hey could you also upvote when you accept an answer, it's nice (and I'm trying to finally get 10k rep aha). thx!